# "Greater than" and "Lesser than" symbols in URL not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, apache, http, iis

i,
I have the following URL which is successfully handled by an Apache Tomcat application:

```
http://localhost:8080/ApplicationX/FileY/UpdateDocument(`<add location="somewhere">ContentZ</add>`).xml?VIEW=RAW
```

For some reason, when I try to handle the same request in IIS with an ASP.NET Http request handler (Class implementing IHttpHandler), I get the 'Bad request' exception and my code is never called.
I have applied this patch in the registry (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/826437) to allow the ':' character but it didn't help with regards to the greater and lesser than characters.

Any ways to make this work? 
Any reasons with it is allowed in Apache but not in IIS?

Cheers.

P.S. I am using IIS 5.1 on a Windows XP workstation with .NET 3.5 SP1.

Comment: How are you calling that URL ? (via ajax, directly copy/pasting in a browser, clicking a generated URL as part of a page, something else ?)

Comment: Copy/pasting in a browser and I've also tried replacing those characters with the corresponding URL escape codes.

Answer (score 11):

Replace `>` by `%3E`

and replace `<` by `%3C`

verified and working.

Answer (score 6):

Try using character entities to escape those characters?:

```
http://localhost:8080/ApplicationX/FileY/UpdateDocument(`&lt;add location="somewhere"&gt;ContentZ&lt;/add&gt;`).xml?VIEW=RAW
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to URLencode your URL, if you want to avoid such problems.

```
    String UrlEncode(String value)
    {
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();

        foreach (char symbol in value)
        {
            if ("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789-_.~".IndexOf(symbol) != -1) result.Append(symbol);
            else result.Append("%u" + String.Format("{0:X4}", (int)symbol));
        }

        return result.ToString();
    }
```

The above supports unicode, and pretty much everything.

Comment: This is a more ideal solution.

Comment: Yeah, but I've run into practical problems, especially in oAuth

Comment: as far as I can tell, this will do the wrong thing for characters beyond the US-ASCII range.

Comment: Well, it's implemented on a Greek website, successfully

Answer (score -2):

You should replace the `<` and `>` signs with `&lt;` and `&gt;` as these characters are special characters. Therefore, see the PHP function urlencode ([urlencode](http://php.net/manual/de/function.urlencode.php)).

Comment: &lt; and &gt; would be the escaping for HTML/XML, not URIs.

Comment: Everything is fine when using urlencode(). I was just not sure what the output was ...